# Page display doesn't behave as intended due to iOS Safari menu bar

Tags: ios, css, ionic-framework, safari, popup

I'm implementing a Ionic web app, and I have a problem with a $ionicPopup that occurs only in iOS Safari.

## The problem

The header and the buttons of my popup, which are supposed to have a fixed position so that they always appear on the screen, are partly hidden because of the menu bar of the browser. Depending on how the user swipes, it's the header or the buttons who are hidden.

I tested it on an actual iPhone 6, and also on [an iPhone emulator](http://www.browserstack.com), from which the following screenshots have been taken.

Here is what happens :

[image: First case scenario]

[image: Second case scenario]

**Please note that everything is displayed just fine when the browser bar doesn't appear.**

Also, **everything works properly on iOS Chrome** (screenshots [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VdQZm.jpg) and [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jKsMy.jpg)).

The CSS for my popup is almost similar to the native Ionic CSS rules, with just one or 2 minor modifications (color, size, etc) :

```
.popup-container .popup {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
    min-height: 200px;
    border-radius: 0px;
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9);
    display: flex; /* Plus all webkits, moz and ms equivalents */
    flex-direction: column; /* Plus all webkits, moz and ms equivalents */
}

.popup .popup-head {
    padding: 15px 10px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #5a9bd5;
    color: white;
}


.popup .popup-body{
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    opacity: 1;
    font-size: 18px;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 10px 30px 10px 30px;
    overflow: auto;
}

.popup .popup-buttons{
    display: flex; /* Plus all webkits, moz and ms equivalents */
    flex-direction: row; /* Plus all webkits, moz and ms equivalents */
    padding: 10px;
    min-height: 65px;
}
```

## My question

How can I get both my header and my buttons to display on iOS Safari, as in the following picture?

[image: Best case scenario]

## My research and attempts

After some research, I saw that my problem might be due to a bigger issue with some mobile browsers where menu bars causes some behavior problems with CSS, and with user interaction in general.

It's being discussed in various places ([1](https://www.eventbrite.com/engineering/mobile-safari-why/), [2](https://forum.webflow.com/t/how-to-deal-with-safari-action-bar-on-iphone/25717), [3](https://benfrain.com/the-ios-safari-menu-bar-is-hostile-to-web-apps-discuss/)).

### Attempt #1

I tried a JS script that I found on [this discussion](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js/issues/2414) and that seemed to solve the author's problem, without any success for me:

```
var height = window.innerHeight;
var a = setInterval(function() {
    $(window).scrollTop(-1);
    resize();
}, 500); // Don't lower more than 500ms, otherwise there will be animation-problems with the  Safari toolbar

$(window).on('resize', function() {
    resize();
});

var resize = function() {
    if(window.innerHeight != height) {
        height = window.innerHeight;
        $('.section').css('height', height + 'px');
    }
};
```

Comment: How are you testing this? Actual real phone? Simulator from XCode?

Comment: I test it on an actual iPhone 6. I also tried on an emulator and the result was the same.
Interesting note: on the Google Chrome device emulator, it works fine, probably because it just reproduces the screen size and not the actual browser behaviour.

Comment: I suppose the content of the popup is not the one pushing the buttons lower, I refer to "My popup content" from your screenshots.

I would try to investigate which values of width/height are referenced for the popup in both cases to have an idea why the difference.

PS: Can you do a test with chrome on iOS also?

Comment: Everything works properly on iOS Chrome, I added links to screenshots on my post as an edit. Indeed, the content of the popup is not pushing the buttons, because in my real application, the content is much bigger than on my screenshots, and it scrolls inside the popups exactly like I want. I will try to dig further into the differences between what works and what doesn't. Thanks for the advice!

Comment: I'm glad if I could help even a little bit ;)